# I want to display a word and excel in web browser. PDF is working but word and excel are not

Tags: browser, ms-word

Can anyone explain me how to display a word and excel in browser.

I had set content type as `application/vnd.ms-excel` for excel but still not working.

PDF is working fine.

Comment: There is no standard for that. PDF needs a plugin to the browser. You can only present a download link to the user and let the browser decide.

Comment: Can you please be more specific what is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your word and excel files as webpage, just select that option webpage in the save as menu.

Comment: if this works for @Shilpa converting the MS Office files to pdf is an option too. And this even makes sure the file looks like the original file.

Comment: Yes, my solution will change the format, Id rather change to PDF too.

Answer (score 0):

A browser is only able to display files from Microsoft Office when the application is installed. For some versions of Microsoft Office viewer applications exist.

But displaying Word and Excel files in modern browsers (especially Internet Explorer) has the drawback that the browser does not display the file in the original window but rather opens a new window.

This in turn is good because current MS Office versions hide some functions and windows when a file is not opened in the application but in the browser. This sometimes makes it impossible to uses formulas in Excel or reopen a file that was opened in readonly mode.

In short: if you want a good experience for your users either accept (if they have it installed) that a second window is opened for the Word and Excel file you present or (if possible) convert it into a html equivalent (which will have a different look) or a pdf (which then automatically is readonly and kind of protected)